# changing a variable based on page content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an external car dealership calculator script, and in order to fit it to my website I need to change the value of objectPrice, based on my page content.

How can I with jQuery change the value of objectPrice?

I have tried following code, but that did not work:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#objectPrice").attr("objectPrice", "500");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div 
  id="externalcalculator" 
  partnerExternalDealerId="1234" 
  objectType="1" 
  make="Audi" 
  model="A6" 
  variant="3,0 TDI" 
  mileage="600" 
  firstregistrationdate="2014-11-25" 
  objectPrice="225000" 
  showaspricelabel="false">...</div>
```

Comment: the id of your div is `externalcalculator` not `objectPrice`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Comment: @mplungjan The typo is one of the issue. But there is another issue with `attr()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your id is not correct, you can use `jQuery("#externalcalculator")`.

But there is another issue, you are using camelCase notation for your attribute. jQuery `.attr()` method transform this attribute into lowercase.

You can use native javascript with `.setAttribute()` to change attribute with camelCase.

Like :

```
jQuery("#externalcalculator").get(0).setAttribute("objectPrice", "500");
```

---

**Note**: Per [http://www.w3.org/](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2) “XHTML documents must use lower case for all HTML element and attribute names.”

Answer (score -1):

Mads Hjorth, based on you snippet above, your're very close to get where you want. You are selecting the wrong div id, you want to change to 
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#externalcalculator").attr("objectPrice", "500");});` This should make the magic.

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions - it has already been pointed out twice